# Swapping between textures on a sprite sheet (OpenGL, C++)

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I'm working on a project where I want to swap between two textures on a sprite sheet using OpenGL.
I have both textures rendering in my window individually with no issues but I can't get them to switch with the key press I have set.
Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong/missing to get it to swap?

```
#include "LUtil.h"
#include <IL/il.h>
#include <IL/ilu.h>
#include "LTexture.h"

int gViewportMode = VIEWPORT_MODE_C;

//Sprite texture
LTexture gArrowTexture;

//Sprite area
LFRect gArrowClips[ 4 ];

bool initGL()
{
//Set the viewport
glViewport( 0.f, 0.f, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );

//Initialize Projection Matrix
glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho( 0.0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0 );

//Initialize Modelview Matrix
glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
glLoadIdentity();

//Initialize clear color
glClearColor( 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f );

//Enable texturing
glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );

//Check for error
GLenum error = glGetError();
if( error != GL_NO_ERROR )
{
    printf( "Error initializing OpenGL! %s\n", gluErrorString(error);
    return false;
}

//Initialize DevIL
ilInit();
ilClearColour( 255, 255, 255, 000 );

//Check for error
ILenum ilError = ilGetError();
if( ilError != IL_NO_ERROR )
{
 printf( "Error initializing DevIL! %s\n", iluErrorString(ilError) );
    return false;
}

return true;
}

bool loadMedia()
{
//Set clip rectangles
if ( gViewportMode == VIEWPORT_MODE_C) {
gArrowClips[ 0 ].x = 0.f;
gArrowClips[ 0 ].y = 0.f;
gArrowClips[ 0 ].w = 330.f;
gArrowClips[ 0 ].h = 355.f;

gArrowClips[ 1 ].x = 330.f;
gArrowClips[ 1 ].y = 0.f;
gArrowClips[ 1 ].w = 310.f;
gArrowClips[ 1 ].h = 480.f;

gArrowClips[ 2 ].x = 0.f;
gArrowClips[ 2 ].y = 355.f;
gArrowClips[ 2 ].w = 330.f;
gArrowClips[ 2 ].h = 125.f;
}
else if ( gViewportMode == VIEWPORT_MODE_N) {
gArrowClips[ 0 ].x = 0.f;
gArrowClips[ 0 ].y = 480.f;
gArrowClips[ 0 ].w = 330.f;
gArrowClips[ 0 ].h = 355.f;

gArrowClips[ 1 ].x = 330.f;
gArrowClips[ 1 ].y = 480.f;
gArrowClips[ 1 ].w = 310.f;
gArrowClips[ 1 ].h = 480.f;

gArrowClips[ 2 ].x = 0.f;
gArrowClips[ 2 ].y = 835.f;
gArrowClips[ 2 ].w = 330.f;
gArrowClips[ 2 ].h = 125.f;
}
//Load texture
if( !gArrowTexture.loadTextureFromFile( "SpriteSheet.png" ) )
{
    printf( "Unable to load texture!\n" );
    return false;
}
return true;
}

void update()
{

}

void render()
{
//Clear color buffer
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

//Render arrows
gArrowTexture.render( 0.f, 0.f, &gArrowClips[ 0 ] );
gArrowTexture.render( SCREEN_WIDTH - gArrowClips[ 1 ].w, 0.f, &gArrowClips[ 1 ] );
gArrowTexture.render( 0.f, SCREEN_HEIGHT - gArrowClips[ 2 ].h, &gArrowClips[ 2 ] );




//Update screen
glutSwapBuffers();

}
void handleKeys( unsigned char key, int x, int y )
{
//If the user presses q
if( key == 'q' )
{
gViewportMode++;
if ( gViewportMode > VIEWPORT_MODE_N ) 
{
gViewportMode == VIEWPORT_MODE_C;
}
}
}
```

Like I said earlier I am able to get the different textures to render by swapping VIEWPORT_MODE_C and VIEWPORT_MODE_N at int gViewPortMode just under my includes.

My issue is that I cannot get them to swap using the key command that switches the viewport so I have to stop the program, change the code, then start it again to change the textures.

Does switching the viewport just not work for this?
If yes, is there an alternative?
If no, what do I need to fix/change?

Comment: In `handleKeys()` why are you testing for equality with `gViewportMode == VIEWPORT_MODE_C` and ignoring the result?

Comment: it was supposed to help keep the cycle going but now that you've said that I'm thinking I can just remove that if statement entirely. Unfortunately I cannot test that right now as I'm away from my house and computer. I'll post an update ASAP.

Comment: Update: I removed the `if ( key == 'q' )
{
gViewportMode++;
if ( gViewportMode > VIEWPORT_MODE_N ) 
{
gViewportMode == VIEWPORT_MODE_C;
}
}`

Comment: I'm still getting the same results, I thought removing it might do something but there was no change.

Comment: I also tried changing the `gViewPortMode == VIEWPORT_MODE_C;` to `gViewPortMode = VIEWPORT_MODE_C;` Sorry for the comment spam...

Comment: Why are you setting `gArrowClips` in `loadMedia`? Why not put all the code for `gArrowClips` in a new function and then call that new function when the q key is pressed after updating `gViewportMode`? I'm assuming `loadMedia` is only called once during initialization, since you don't call it anywhere in the code sample you provided.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenGL code looks fine, it's just a matter of updating `gArrowClips` every time the *q* key is pressed. From the code sample you provided, it looks like you're only setting `gArrowClips` when `loadMedia()` is called. Since you never call `loadMedia()` after the *q* key is pressed, meaning `gArrowClips` is never updated, no changes to the textures take effect. I'm assuming `loadMedia()` is only ever called once when your program starts since it handles loading a texture from a file and you don't call it anywhere else from your code.

I haven't tested the code below, but it should do what you're asking. I essentially moved the code you had in `loadMedia()` that handles setting `gArrowClips` to its own function, `updateSpriteAreas()`. I then call that function once when `loadMedia()` is called to initialize `gArrowClips`, and again when the *q* key is pressed in `handleKeys()` to change the sprite textures.

```
#include "LUtil.h"
#include <IL/il.h>
#include <IL/ilu.h>
#include "LTexture.h"

int gViewportMode = VIEWPORT_MODE_C;

//Sprite texture
LTexture gArrowTexture;

//Sprite area
LFRect gArrowClips[ 4 ];

bool initGL()
{
    //Set the viewport
    glViewport( 0.f, 0.f, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );

    //Initialize Projection Matrix
    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho( 0.0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0 );

    //Initialize Modelview Matrix
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    //Initialize clear color
    glClearColor( 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f );

    //Enable texturing
    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );

    //Check for error
    GLenum error = glGetError();
    if( error != GL_NO_ERROR )
    {
        printf( "Error initializing OpenGL! %s\n", gluErrorString(error);
        return false;
    }

    //Initialize DevIL
    ilInit();
    ilClearColour( 255, 255, 255, 000 );

    //Check for error
    ILenum ilError = ilGetError();
    if( ilError != IL_NO_ERROR )
    {
        printf( "Error initializing DevIL! %s\n", iluErrorString(ilError) );
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

//Move the sprite changes to a new function that gets called every time you make changes
void updateSpriteAreas()
{
    //Set clip rectangles
    if ( gViewportMode == VIEWPORT_MODE_C) {
        gArrowClips[ 0 ].x = 0.f;
        gArrowClips[ 0 ].y = 0.f;
        gArrowClips[ 0 ].w = 330.f;
        gArrowClips[ 0 ].h = 355.f;

        gArrowClips[ 1 ].x = 330.f;
        gArrowClips[ 1 ].y = 0.f;
        gArrowClips[ 1 ].w = 310.f;
        gArrowClips[ 1 ].h = 480.f;

        gArrowClips[ 2 ].x = 0.f;
        gArrowClips[ 2 ].y = 355.f;
        gArrowClips[ 2 ].w = 330.f;
        gArrowClips[ 2 ].h = 125.f;
    }
    else if ( gViewportMode == VIEWPORT_MODE_N) {
        gArrowClips[ 0 ].x = 0.f;
        gArrowClips[ 0 ].y = 480.f;
        gArrowClips[ 0 ].w = 330.f;
        gArrowClips[ 0 ].h = 355.f;

        gArrowClips[ 1 ].x = 330.f;
        gArrowClips[ 1 ].y = 480.f;
        gArrowClips[ 1 ].w = 310.f;
        gArrowClips[ 1 ].h = 480.f;

        gArrowClips[ 2 ].x = 0.f;
        gArrowClips[ 2 ].y = 835.f;
        gArrowClips[ 2 ].w = 330.f;
        gArrowClips[ 2 ].h = 125.f;
    }
}

bool loadMedia()
{
    //Initialize the sprite rectangles
    updateSpriteAreas()

    //Load texture
    if( !gArrowTexture.loadTextureFromFile( "SpriteSheet.png" ) )
    {
        printf( "Unable to load texture!\n" );
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void update()
{

}

void render()
{
    //Clear color buffer
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    //Render arrows
    gArrowTexture.render( 0.f, 0.f, &gArrowClips[ 0 ] );
    gArrowTexture.render( SCREEN_WIDTH - gArrowClips[ 1 ].w, 0.f, &gArrowClips[ 1 ] );
    gArrowTexture.render( 0.f, SCREEN_HEIGHT - gArrowClips[ 2 ].h, &gArrowClips[ 2 ] );

    //Update screen
    glutSwapBuffers();

}
void handleKeys( unsigned char key, int x, int y )
{
    //If the user presses q
    if( key == 'q' )
    {
        gViewportMode++;
        if ( gViewportMode > VIEWPORT_MODE_N ) 
        {
            gViewportMode == VIEWPORT_MODE_C;
        }
        //Update the sprite rectangles so the texture change takes effect
        updateSpriteAreas();
    }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work to update the textures so I tried rendering a couple basic quads of different colors under each viewport mode. The first quad rendered fine but the second wouldn't come up at all when I pressed "q" (the window just remained the same) so I now believe this to be a problem with my viewport. This is the same way I always change my viewport and I've never had any issues with it until now. Does anyone know what I can do to fix this? Any alternatives?

Comment: Ok so I played around with it a little more and got a red quad to render once I press q. The new issue is once the red quad is rendered it tints the textures red and even worse once I press q again it removes the quad but the textures stay red.

Comment: I tried to add `glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);` into my handleKeys() function which obviously turns all the textures white when I pressed q. But once I added in a `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);` under it after the `gViewportMode++;` it stopped doing anything. I was however able to get it to switch from white quads back to textures and vise versa by putting the `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);` in its own key command. I'm completely stumped right now and Google doesn't have the answers I need.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue simply by turning the one sprite sheet into 2(1 sprite sheet for each set of images)and adding an int with a value of 0 then put an if and else if statement in my handle keys function that both check if q is pressed then check the value of the int. In the if statement if the value of the int is 0 when q is pressed, it will change the image and add 1 to the int. In the else if statement it checks if the value of the int is 1 when q is pressed, change the image, then subtract 1 from the int.